# Factory is returning a function instead of the return value of the function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I had an application pretty much figured out until I realized that I am making way to many calls to database api and as a result the app is lagging. I am trying to set up a way to keep the current scope accurate when adding and removing items from the $scope object instead of having to request the entire list from the database every time. So I figured from all I've read that a factory is the way to go. That way I can pull the data from the database once, then after successfully adding or deleting entries through the api I can just manipulate the current scope instead of requesting the entire list again. My question is (with an example), How do I fetch a list of users from the api and add that to the scope. Then when I add or delete users from the list I can just remove them from the scope without fetching the list all over again from the api?

Here is my factory:

```
app.factory("UsersFactory",['Data',function(Data){
    var users;

    function init(){
        Data.get('users')
        .then(function (results) {
            users = results;
        });
    }

    init();

    function getUsers(){
        return users;
    }

    return {
        getUsers:getUsers
    }

}]);
```

And after injecting the factory in the controller:

```
console.log(UsersFactory.getUsers);
```

This returns the function but not the return value of the function.

I have also tried:

```
console.log(UsersFactory.getUsers());
```

Which returns undefined;

I would actually like to do all this in the resolve for the state (ui-router) but in the controller directly is ok too i guess.

Any help would be ap;appreciated and feel free to ask me to clarify anything. I'm not very good at clearly asking questions.

Comment: is this because the init() function is making an async call? and that `users` isnt populated yet?

Comment: You might want to read the caching section in angular documentation for [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to return a promise from your `factory`:

```
app.factory("UsersFactory", ['Data', function(Data) {
  var factory = {
    getUsers: getUsers
  };

  return factory;

  function getUsers() {
    return Data.get('users');
  }
}]);
```

Then, in your `controller`:

```
app.controller("UsersController", ['$scope', 'UsersFactory', function($scope, UsersFactory) {
  function getResponse(response) {
    $scope.users = response.data;
  }

  function getError(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }

  UsersFactory.getUsers()
    .then(getResponse);
    .catch(getError);
}]);
```

Comment: This is the right approach, in general. But OP also said he wants to "[avoid having to] request the entire list from the database every time" and that he wants to "pull the data from the database once" and then just modify it as needed. So as an enhancement, I'd recommend persisting the results of the first call inside the service/factory, and then just returning that data on any following calls instead of making a new request on each call to 'getUsers'.

Comment: Well, he has already the `$scope.users` with the entire list, now he just needs to manipulate it. There's no necessity of call `UsersFactory` again.

Comment: In this case, you're probably right. I was thinking he might want to use the 'user' data in another controller. But he'd need to add another 'update' method to the factory to be able to update it with the modified scope version too in that case. I'm probably just thinking too far ahead, but that's how I like to structure/use my services, anyways - by keeping the important app state in the services, and then using methods exposed by the services inside the controllers, rather than just as http request wrappers. That way you have a centralized, single "source of truth" for your application.

Comment: Can you please help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700616/how-to-make-scrollbar-scroll-horizontally-on-right-and-left-on-click-of-next-and

Answer (score -1):

Factory:

```
app.factory("UsersFactory",function(Data) {
UpDateUserinfo:function(){
       var inf;
       inf=Data.get('users');
       return inf;
    }
})
```

Controller:

```
 app.controller("UsersController", function($scope, UsersFactory){
 UsersFactory.UpDateUserinfo().$promise.then(function(data){
 $scope.users=data
  })
})
```

Comment: This won't work - in OP's example, Data.get() returns a promise (indicated by the fact that he's calling .then() on it). In this example, you are assigning a promise to $scope.data, which is not the actual 'users' data.